# MongoDB / BSON Save Map

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, bson

So I have a array I want to save and load in my BSON Doc this is what I currently have

```
addSaver("log") { account->
    val doc = Document()
    doc.append("clicked", account.collectionLog.clicked).
}

addLoader("log") { account, doc ->
    account.collectionLog.clicked= doc["clicked"] as MutableMap<String, Int>
}
```

But I seem to get the following errors

Saving:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at org.bson.codecs.DocumentCodec.writeMap(DocumentCodec.java:208)
```

Loading:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Integer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.bson.Document.put(Document.java:52)
```

All my other types save and work as they should but this is the only type I can't seem to get working as it should